# Given the start function write a function to print Student letter grades and class average

Tags: javascript

Given the "start function", I had to create a function that prints an output of 20 random student Letter Grades.
At the end print the class average. My code is not printing correctly. I need help with the output.

here is my code

```
var examGrade;
var letter;
function start(){
    var NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS = 20;
    for(var i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS; i++){
        
        var examGrade = Randomizer.nextInt(50,100);
        var letter = getLetterGrade(examGrade);
        println("you received " + letter + "for your grade of " + examGrade);
        
    }
}

function getLetterGrade(){
    if (examGrade >= 91 && n >= 100){
       println("A");
       
    }else if (examGrade >= 81 && n >= 90){
      println("A");
      
    }else if (examGrade >= 71 && n >= 80){
       println("C");
       
    }else if (examGrade >= 61 && n >= 70){
     println("D");
      
    }else if (examGrade <61){ 
       println("F");
    }

}
```

My output is incorrect
It prints:

```
you received undefinedfor your grade of 97
```

Here is how it should look:

```
you received A for your grade of 97
you received C for your grade of 97
    
The class average is 76.56
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: So what is the problem? You just explained to us what you were supposed to do and posted some code. The community requires you to explain what is/isn't working and any other problems you are aware of with the code. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that `println(...)` isn't used in javascript. You should use `console.log(...)` instead.

Comment: My code is not printing correctly.  I'm using CodeHS, and it takes println(..) but I can also use console.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments in the code. There are several errors (1-6):

```js
var examGrade;
var letter;
function start(){
    var NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS = 20;
    for(var i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS; i++){

        var examGrade = getRandomInt(50,100); // 2. This is how you generate random numbers (see function getRandomInt)
        var letter = getLetterGrade(examGrade);
        document.writeln("you received " + letter + " for your grade of " + examGrade + "<br>"); // 3. Use "document.writeln" to write lines in browser

    }
}

/* Copied from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random */
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

// 4. You need to return the letter from the function
function getLetterGrade(examGrade){ // 5. You need to catch the value sent to the function here
    if (examGrade >= 91 && examGrade >= 100){ // 6. You need to use the parameter "examGrade" (not "n")
       return "A";

    }else if (examGrade >= 81 && examGrade >= 90){
      return "A";

    }else if (examGrade >= 71 && examGrade >= 80){
       return "C";

    }else if (examGrade >= 61 && examGrade >= 70){
     return "D";

    }else if (examGrade <61){ 
       return "F";
    }

}

start() // 1. Need to run the function "start"
```

Comment: When a question has so many small mistakes, instead of answering, feel free to just flag the question for closure as needing more focus. The goal of SO is to make a library of Q&As that help future readers, and this type of question will hardly help anyone else but the OP (it's unlikely that someone else makes exactly the same mistakes)...